# Multiple Virtual Directories pointed to the same folder on web server

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-applications

I have a presentation web farm with four load-balanced servers. I have one web application with two website domains that represent that application. Rather than constantly push to two different folder locations, I figured I can push to one location and have a virtual directory on each website point to the single folder on the webserver.

Here is the setup:
The load balancer is CoyotePoint. The web framework is asp.net 3.5. IIS 6 (slowing moving to 7).

I'm concerned about performance in a production environment. Are there any ramifications to having two websites with virtual directories pointing to the same directory on disk? Should I also be worried about application pools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found what I was looking for. It's called [CentralizedWebFarmManagement for IIS](http://www.iis.net/overview/CentralizedWebFarmManagement). Specifically, I think the [Shared-configuration](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/264/shared-configuration/), and [Web Deployment Tools for Web Farm](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/670/using-the-web-deployment-tool-for-web-farms/) is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what this application is doing.  If you're doing anything at all fancy with System.IO you're going to run into issues.

There are other ways to make the pushing of files easier.  I highly recommend creating a quick bat file with a few robocopy commands in it.

Comment: Pushing files is not a big deal really. I use beyond compare for that. My primary concern is performance. The application primarily communicates with a sql server database and some web services.